# How to use powershell pattern matching to find and run a .bat file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm a powershell noob and despite my googling skills I've been unable to work out how to find the directory of a file based on a pattern in powershell, then run that file.

These are the requirements...

- Start in a particular folder (C:\TFS)
- Search that folder for a particular batch file named 'SpecFlow.bat' and return the folder and file path
- Run the file from the directory returned in the previous step

I had something like this but I don't really know what I am doing

```
Set-Location -Path C:\TFS
$a = Get-ChildItem C:\TFS -Filter SpecFlow.bat -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }
Start-Process $a
```

This appears to find and run the file, but in the 'C:\TFS' directory. As a result I get the following error in my cmd window...

```
C:\TFS>SpecRun.exe run default.srprofile /basefolder:..\..\bin\release /outputfolder:output /report:MyReport.html
'SpecRun.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Where am I going wrong?

For bonus points, can I convert my batch file to all powershell? The contents of the batch file are....

```
SpecRun.exe run default.srprofile /basefolder:..\..\bin\release /outputfolder:output /report:MyReport.html
```

pause

There are dependant files in the same directory as SpecRun.exe.

Thanks

Comment: If `SpecRun.exe` isn't in the current directory or `%PATH%` you'll need to make that directory current or include it's full path, _instead of just it's file name_. You already appear to be making `C:\TFS` current, _(which is what you appear to be saying is your issue)_, so perhaps you want to use, `Set-Location -Path {C:\MyFolder}\packages\SpecRun.Runner.{version}\tools` instead.

Comment: @Compo. I was looking to get the directory of a SpecFlow.bat file (which I've put in the same directory as SpecRun.exe) based on a pattern match of the file name only. I could specifically navigate to `{C:\MyFolder}\packages\SpecRun.Runner.{version}\tools` but what if the version of `SpecRun.Runner.{version}` were to change?

Comment: Konzy262, would it not make sense to `Set-Location` to the retrieved path from your `Get-ChildItem` search then? Additionally, `Start-Process` has a `-WorkingDirectory` parameter which can be used to do exactly what you need, _(the default without it would be the current directory)_. It also has an `-ArgumentList` parameter which can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "SpecFlow.bat"}
cd $file.directory
StartProcess $file
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.